# How to build anchor link and trigger click event?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery version 2.0.3 and I'm trying to build the jQuery script but the triggering of the click event does not work.

Is the function `click()` invalid? How do you usually make this work?

```
var htmlAnchor = "";
htmlAnchor += "<a href='testcase.html?x=Foo' target='_blank'></a>";
$(htmlAnchor).appendTo("body").click().remove();
```

Comment: Why not using `window.location`?

Comment: For "target='_blank'" to popup new window?

Comment: You could use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

Comment: What do you mean "there is nothing between your anchor tags"?  I only have 1 anchor tag.

Comment: I've answered you question since I think it can be useful for futur users. I just think it's better not to use that to open a new window.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just understood

Comment: I don't know about the window.open.  The web browser having some itching tendency to block the pop-up...

Comment: If pop-up is a problem there is no way to curb it. Any automatic window open will be pop-up

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - True.   I can use both window.open() and your answer below.   That will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.click()` on a jQuery object trigger the jQuery event `click`. What you want is to trigger the default click event on JavaScript. So you need to select the HTMLElement, just like that :

```
var htmlAnchor = "";
htmlAnchor += "<a href='testcase.html?x=Foo' target='_blank'></a>";
$(htmlAnchor).appendTo("body").detach()[0].click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/127gkdvr/

Comment: Wow.  That's nice.  It works great!  I never heard of detach().   I'll accept your answer, plus the window.open() and I'll decided which in the end.  Thanks.

Comment: @fletchsod yeah, i've used detach, but remove work aswell. Just be sure to finish with `[0].click();`, but you can use etheir of those two methods.

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and this: window.open('testcase.html?x=Foo')?

Comment: @AdrianoGalessoAlves `window.open` is, IMO, better. I am the one that suggested it in the comment. I also said *"I've answered you question since I think it can be useful for futur users. I just think it's better not to use that to open a new window."*

Comment: Ah ok! I though you had saw something that I don't!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Web Browser brand and OS platform have certain flavoring that differ a little, also anti-virus softwares.  Not really much different with either javascript script.

Comment: @fletchsod If it was so easy to open a pop up without consent, trust me, it would have been fixed really fast ;)

Answer (score 0):

make one .js file :-

### test.js:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").trigger('click');
})
```

### In html file:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var htmlAnchor = "";
   htmlAnchor += "<a href='testcase.html?x=Foo' target='_blank'></a>";
 var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'test.js';
headID.appendChild(newScript);
</script>
```